# Fixed width rows in a CSV?

Tags: csv, text-editing

I have a file whose newline delimiter has been accidentally erased.  Now I have a whole bunch of 216-character lines, all displaying on a single line.  Using the fact that I know the lines will be fixed width, is there a (windows) tool which could insert a line break every 216 characters?

Alternatively, I can get a copy of this file as a CSV.  Again, no linebreaks.  But this time, I would have to insert a line break every 6 commas.

I have tried importing these to Excel as a CSV, but that requires me to scroll the entire width of the file, removing their line breaks, and inserting my own every 216 characters-- definitely not a solution.

Comment: You can write a PowerShell script to break it up and then write it out to a text file or CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have or can get Perl, try out this command in your shell:

```
perl -C -nlE 'say $1 while (/(\G.{216})/g)' your_input_file
```